# Disable magic mouse back-forward gesture only in XCODE

Tags: mac, xcode, magic-mouse

Is it possible to disable magic mouse back-forward gesture only in XCODE?
While in browser it is fine, in XCODE it just totaly unwanted feature for me.

Comment: Please for the log of god someone find an answer to this!

Comment: You cannot configure application specific gestures in OS X itself. You could though try the free BetterTouchTool to add browser specific gestures for back/forward and disable the global system gesture. http://www.bettertouchtool.net

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but @MacLemon's suggestion is probably the best way for now.  Unless you want to write a custom daemon that checks for the program being open and writing the string in the plist file for the mouse...

Comment: @nerdwaller it would be great if you could tell me which string exactly disables 'swipe between pages' gesture :) I've already written daemon which tracks application switching, but I can't figure out what string I should write to defaults to disable pages swipe thing.

Comment: @dig It will be somewhere similar to this: `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseHorizontalScroll -bool NO`  That obviously disables Horizontal Scrolling, but it will be around there.  I would look for you, but I got rid of my apple a while ago.  Just run `sudo find / -name "com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMutitouch.mouse"`, should get you to the right file and you could look through for swipe gestures.  The command to disable should look similar to the above.  When I get home, I can try to find my wife's laptop if she will let me try it.

Comment: @nerdwaller I've tried `defaults find com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse` which brings list of keys in mouse domain. However setting both  MouseHorizontalScroll and MouseMomentumScroll to 0 doesn't do anything to scrolling at all:( I guess that checking box in GUI prefs tweaks other values somewhere

Comment: @nerdwaller actually via GUI I can disable swipe, but leave horizontal scrolling

Comment: continue my investigation, `defaults write -g AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO` clear checkbox in System Preferences, but does not actually disable swipe gesture

Answer (score 5):

In short: disable it on the mouse:

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleEnableMouseSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO

for trackpads use:

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO

Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024231/prevent-disable-xcode-scroll-navigation]

Comment: wow, thanks. Xcode is so crappy that it hangs constantly if the back swipe is on. Did I mention I hate xcode? thanks.

Comment: I can't count how many years I suffered from this bug. My finger just moves 1 mm on the Magic Mouse and puff, Xcode starts swiping, and my Interface Designer or SwiftUI Previews is gone, has to be reloaded. You saved countless hours of waiting for me, sir!